# How prevent Conflict between two $(this) in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make some div dynamically and give them .css('display','none') at first

i want to set a background image for these divs but i want to load those backgrounds only when they are visible, i'm using this code to make a loading gif on div then hide it when background image is loaded

```
$("<img/>").attr('src', 'Groups/items/thumbs/101.jpg').load(function() {
    $(this).remove(); // this $(this) back to $(<img/>)

    $("#Frames_img").css(   
        'background-image','url("Groups/items/thumbs/101.jpg")'});
    $("#Frames_loader").hide();
});
$("#Frames_img").addClass('Page');
$("#Frames_img").data("Page", i);
```

i don have problem till here but my problem start here on the code i wrote for my pages that i made them dynamically too, i want to when i click on my pages button then what ever div that has visible value on display get their image source and load it as background image

now my code is like this :

```
$("#Frames_img").data("imgurl", 'Groups/items/thumbs/101.jpg')
```

and i wrote these on my pages button

```
if ($(".Page"+$(this).data("Page")).is(':visible')) {
    $("#Stage").find( $(".Page"+$(this).data("Page")) ).each(function(){                                    
        $("<img/>").attr('src', ''+$(this).data("imgurl")+'').load(function() {
            $(this).remove(); // this $(this) back to $(<img/>)
            $("#Frames_img").css(   
                'background-image','url("'+$(this).data("imgurl")+'")'});
            $("#Frames_loader").hide();
        });
    });
}
```

as you can see because i add $("") inside each then it overwrites my $(this) address from those divs that have .Page1 class for example - to $("/")

how can i manage this problem to make them work  ?

if i dont use $(this).data() information on my divs then i cannot bring back their background images and only first image will go to last div or to a random dive and thats  the problem

and the main problem is here that i want to get to know that my div has its own background-image loaded so i can remove my loading gif animation and i only found this useful method $("") but when i use it in this case it will overwrite my $(this) address, or i dont know how can i refer to my previous $(this) address that was upper than my $("")

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a 'temp' variable `var thisCopy = $(this);`

```
if ($(".Page"+$(this).data("Page")).is(':visible')) {
    $("#Stage").find( $(".Page"+$(this).data("Page")) ).each(function(){

        var thisCopy = $(this);
        $("<img/>").attr('src', ''+$(this).data("imgurl")+'').load(function() {
            $(this).remove(); // this $(this) back to $(<img/>)
            $("#Frames_img").css('background-image','url("'+thisCopy.data("imgurl")+'")');
            $("#Frames_loader").hide()
        });
    })
}
```

or use some closure

```
if ($(".Page"+$(this).data("Page")).is(':visible')) {
    $("#Stage").find( $(".Page"+$(this).data("Page")) ).each(
        (function(stage){
            return function(){
                $("<img/>").attr('src', '' + $(this).data("imgurl") + '').load(function(){
                    $(this).remove(); // this $(this) back to $(<img/>)
                    $("#Frames_img").css('background-image', 'url("' + stage.data("imgurl") + '")');
                    $("#Frames_loader").hide()
                });
            };
        })($(this))
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, your first method worked like a charm, but second one didn't worked for me, btw i'm very happy and fyi you saved my job

Comment: I edited the second part, i forgot something. (the $). I'm glad that's helped you